# Simple transformation question

Tags: linear-algebra

> (a) Let $B=\{1,t,t^2\}$ be the standard basis for $P_2(\mathbb R)$. Compute $[T]^B_B$.
>
> Solution: Since $T(1)=1$, $T(t)=t+1$ and $T\left(t^2\right)=(t+1)^2$, we find $$[T]^B_B=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\0&1&2\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

This is a solution to a practice exam problem. I've always struggled with these problems. I sort of know what I'm doing, but when I got my solution it was literally the **transpose** of their solution.

Comment: I solved it by finding T(B)=1,t+1,t$^2$+2t+1. Then I represented T(B) as a linear combination of 1,t,t$^2$ and got the first row (1,0,0) then (1,1,0) then (1,2,1) but shouldn't these be rows so you can matrix multiply, why would they be columns

Answer (score 0):

You should write each image of basis elements how linear combination of own basis. Then, $T(1)=1=1.1+0.t+0.t^2, T(t)=t+1=1.1+1.t+0.t^2$ and $T(t+1)=(t=1)^2=t^2+2t+1=1.1+2.t+1.t^2$. Now you write the coefficients in column of matrix:
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)$$

Comment: okay but why is it a column matrix and not row, that is my question. Don't I need to use it to matrix multiply since it is the matrix representation of the transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
\begin{array}{lclclcl}
T(1)   & = & \color{red}{1}\cdot1 & + & \color{blue}{0}\,t & + & \color{purple}{0}\,t^2 \\
T(t)   & = & \color{red}{1}\cdot1 & + & \color{blue}{1}\,t & + & \color{purple}{0}\,t^2 \\
T(t^2) & = & \color{red}{1}\cdot1 & + & \color{blue}{2}\,t & + & \color{purple}{2}\,t^2
\end{array}
This implies that
$$
[T]_B^B=
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}{1}    & \color{red}{1}    & \color{red}{1}    \\
\color{blue}{0}   & \color{blue}{1}   & \color{blue}{2}   \\
\color{purple}{0} & \color{purple}{0} & \color{purple}{2} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The point here is that this is how $[T]_B^B$ is *defined*. The coefficients in front of each basis vector become the rows of $[T]_B^B$.